# spectral sequence of filtration for homotopy groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, spectral-sequences

I was listening to a course on algebraic topology. Our professor constructed a spectral sequence for a filtered space which computes homology. The construction only used relative homology groups and exact sequence of a triple. Both notions have their analogs in homotopy groups. Is there a spectral sequence of a filtered space which computes homotopy groups instead of homology?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.14931

Comment: Can you add some more detail about the construction that you saw? My guess is that its a spectral sequence arising from a filtered chain complex, but homotopy groups don't come from a chain complex in that way. Without seeing exactly what you mean, I would also make sure that you don't use excision anywhere. If I had to guess, the analogous thing that you're looking for can be found in the *stable* homotopy groups which are a (generalized) homology theory.